# Would a JMS Topic suffice in this situation? Or should I look elsewhere?

Tags: java, jms

There is one controlling entity and several 'worker' entities. The controlling entity requests certain data from the worker entities, which they will fetch and return in their own manner.

Since the controlling entity can agnostic about the worker entities (and the working entities can be added/removed at any point), putting a JMS provider in between them sounds like a good idea. That's the assumption at least.

Since it is an one-to-many relation (controller -> workers), a JMS Topic would be the right solution. But, since the controlling entity is depending on the return values of the workers, request/reply functionality would be nice as well (somewhere, I read about the `TopicRequester` but I cannot seem to find a working example). Request/reply is typical Queue functionality.

As an attempt to use topics in a request/reply sort-of-way, I created two JMS topis: `request` and `response`. The controller publishes to the `request` topic and is subscribed to the `response` topic. Every worker is subscribed to the `request` topic and publishes to the `response` topic. To match requests and responses the controller will subscribe for each request to the `response` topic with a filter (using a session id as the value). The messages workers publish to the `response` topic have the session id associated with them.

Now this does not feel like a solution (rather it uses JMS as a hammer and treats the problem (and some more) as a nail). Is JMS in this situation a solution at all? Or are there other solutions I'm overlooking?

Comment: With a Topic all workers will get all messages, if you want to use the messaging system to distribute the work you should use a Queue.

Comment: Using a queue only one worker will get the message, but the 'problem' is the workers are heterogeneous. The controlling entity should end up with the aggregated results of all workers.

Comment: Do you mean that several types of workers will each contribute part of the result that will then be sort of reassembled by the controller?  Or do the different workers each just react to "their" type of work and thus each message == just 1 type of worker?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach sort of makes sense to me. I think a messaging system could work. I think using topics are wrong. Take a look at the wiki page for [Enterprise Service Bus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_service_bus). It's a little more complicated than you need, but the basic idea for your use case, is that you have a worker that is capable of reading from one queue, doing some processing and adding the processed data back to another queue.

The problem with a topic is that all workers will get the message at the same time and they will all work on it independently. It sounds like you only want one worker at a time working on each request. I think you have it as a topic so different types of workers can also listen to the same queue and only respond to certain requests. For that, you are better off just creating a new queue for each type of work. You could potentially have them in pairs, so you have a work_a_request queue and work_a_response queue. Or if your controller is capable of figuring out the type of response from the data, they can all write to a single response queue.

If you haven't chosen an Message Queue vendor yet, I would recommend [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) as it's easy to set-up, easy to add new queues (especially dynamically) and has really good spring support (although most major messaging systems have spring support and you may not even be using spring).

I'm also not sure what you are accomplishing the filters. If you ensure the messages to the workers contain all the information needed to do the work and the response messages back contain all the information your controller needs to finish the processing, I don't think you need them.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use two JMS queues.

The first one is the one that all of the requests go on. The workers will listen to the queue, and process them in their own time, in their own way.

Once complete, they will put bundle the request with the response and put that on another queue for the final process to handle. This way there's no need for the the submitting process to retain the requests, they just follow along with the entire procedure. A final process will listen to the second queue, and handle the request/response pairs appropriately.

If there's no need for the message to be reliable, or if there's no need for the actual processes to span JVMs or machines, then this can all be done with a single process and standard java threading (such as BlockingQueues and ExecutorServices).

If there's a need to accumulate related responses, then you'll need to capture whatever grouping data is necessary and have the Queue 2 listening process accumulate results. Or you can persist the results in a database.

For example, if you know your working set has five elements, you can queue up the requests with that information (1 of 5, 2 of 5, etc.). As each one finishes, the final process can update the database, counting elements. When it sees all of the pieces have been completed (in any order), it marks the result as complete. Later you would have some audit process scan for incomplete jobs that have not finished within some time (perhaps one of the messages erred out), so you can handle them better. Or the original processors can write the request to a separate "this one went bad" queue for mitigation and resubmission.

If you use JMS with transaction, if one of the processors fails, the transaction will roll back and the message will be retained on the queue for processing by one of the surviving processors, so that's another advantage of JMS.

The trick with this kind of processing is to try and push the state with message, or externalize it and send references to the state, thus making each component effectively stateless. This aids scaling and reliability since any component can fail (besides catastrophic JMS failure, naturally), and just pick up where you left off when you get the problem resolved an get them restarted.

If you're in a request/response mode (such as a servlet needing to respond), you can use Servlet 3.0 Async servlets to easily put things on hold, or you can put a local object on a internal map, keyed with the something such as the Session ID, then you Object.wait() in that key. Then, your Queue 2 listener will get the response, finalize the processing, and then use the Session ID (sent with message and retained through out the pipeline) to look up 
the object that you're waiting on, then it can simply Object.notify() it to tell the servlet to continue.

Yes, this sticks a thread in the servlet container while waiting, that's why the new async stuff is better, but you work with the hand you're dealt. You can also add a timeout to the Object.wait(), if it times out, the processing took to long so you can gracefully alert the client.

This basically frees you from filters and such, and reply queues, etc. It's pretty simple to set it all up.

Answer (score 0):

Well actual answer should depend upon whether your worker entities are external parties, physical located outside network, time expected for worker entity to finish their work etc..but problem you are trying to solve is one-to-many communication...u added jms protocol in your system just because you want all entities to be able to talk in jms protocol or asynchronous is reason...former reason does not make sense...if it is latter reason, you can choose other communication protocol like one-way web service call.
You can use latest java concurrent APIs to create multi-threaded asynchronous one-way web service call to different worker entities...